# jQuery: set tooltip position one time but without "activate" it on the whole document

Tags: jquery, position, tooltip

I use:

```
 $(document).tooltip({
            position: {
                my: 'left center',
                at: 'right+60 center'
              }
        });
```

It works, but tooltips are displayed also for elements for which I don't want tooltip.

I know I can use

```
$("textarea[name=thename]").tooltip();
$("textarea[name=thename2]").tooltip();
....
$("input[name=name3]").tooltip();
```

but is it possible to set the position only one time?

**EDIT**

I've tried with

```
 $.tooltip({
   position: {
     my: 'left center',
     at: 'right+60 center'
    }
 });
```

but nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I can think of is assigning a position in a variable:

```
var myPos = { my: 'left center', at: 'right+60 center' };
```

And then using it later:

```
$("textarea[name=thename]").tooltip({position: myPos});
$("textarea[name=thename2]").tooltip({position: myPos);
```

Using it on the `$(document)` will attach it to the whole document and its descendants, that's why it appears no matter where you point your mouse.